# React redux doesn't automatically render the changed things

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a problem with React redux. And I want to display the current state immediately. Unfortunately this doesn't work as intended. The changed data is only displayed correctly after the page has been reloaded.

This is the Main Part in my Articel.js

```
const buySomething = async (articelId) => {
 await axios.put(`/articel/request/${articelId}`).then((res) => {
  dispatch(requested(currentUser._id));
  setSnackbarMessage(res.data);
  setOpen(true);
});
};
```

Articel model:

```
requested: {
  type: [String],
  default: [],
},
```

articelSlice.js

```
 const initialState = {
  currentArticel: null,
  loading: false,
  error: false,
 };

  requested: (state, action) => {
  if (!state.currentArticel.requested.includes(action.payload)) {
    state.currentArticel.requested.push(action.payload);
  } else {
    state.currentArticel.requested.splice(
      state.currentArticel.requested.findIndex(
        (userId) => userId === action.payload
      ),
      1
    );
  }
},
```

Complete articelSlice Code:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
currentArticel: null,
loading: false,
error: false,
};

export const articelSlice = createSlice({
name: "articel",
initialState,
reducers: {
fetchStart: (state) => {
  state.loading = true;
},
 fetchSuccess: (state, action) => {
  state.loading = false;
  state.currentArticel = action.payload;
 },
 fetchFailure: (state) => {
  state.loading = false;
  state.error = true;
},
   requested: (state, action) => {
  if (!state.currentArticel.requested.includes(action.payload)) {
    state.currentArticel.requested.push(action.payload);
  } else {
    state.currentArticel.requested.splice(
      state.currentArticel.requested.findIndex(
        (userId) => userId === action.payload
      ),
      1
    );
  }
},
like: (state, action) => {
  if (!state.currentArticel.likes.includes(action.payload)) {
    state.currentArticel.likes.push(action.payload);
    state.currentArticel.dislikes.splice(
      state.currentArticel.dislikes.findIndex(
        (userId) => userId === action.payload
      ),
      1
    );
  }
},
 dislike: (state, action) => {
  if (!state.currentArticel.dislikes.includes(action.payload)) {
    state.currentArticel.dislikes.push(action.payload);
    state.currentArticel.likes.splice(
      state.currentArticel.likes.findIndex(
        (userId) => userId === action.payload
      ),
      1
    );
  }
  },
 },
});

export const {
fetchStart,
fetchSuccess,
fetchFailure,
like,
dislike, 
requested,
} = articelSlice.actions;

export default articelSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: You're supposed to use redux-thunk or redux-saga for async effects like data fetching.

Comment: Also, you need to bear in mind that both `push()` and `splice()` mutate your state in-place, hence no re-renders would be triggered. So, you need to refactor your reducer to do immutable state updates (shallow copy -> modify -> return modified copy)/

Comment: Furthermore, dragging around `axios` inside your event handlers (which, I assume, `buySomething` is) doesn't seem to be a good solution from general design prospective. To make your design a bit more SOLID, you'd better split axios calls out of your components (who knows, maybe you'll decide to stick to fetch or graphql instead of REST someday) and expose that as universal method to be called within component.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov it's a good practice, but not necessary to use middleware for async stuff - and `push` as well as `splice` are 100% okay assuming that OP is using Redux Toolkit `createSlice`, which by the looks of it they probably are. Unfortunately they are not sharing enough code to actually point out any error.

Comment: @phry yes, i use redux toolkit. Ok what should i also post ? The whole articelSlice (createSlice) code ?

Comment: The full slice, the full component and maybe also explain how you determine that the store does not change. Do you look into the DevTools?

Comment: @phry have edit my post. I have already posted where I use the dispatcher.
As already mentioned, the current refresh of the page does not work.
Only after I manually reloaded them.
In my MongoDB, the data is immediately visible after I called dispatch or after calling axios

Comment: @Captai-N I don't see any use of `useSelector` here - how would your page ever access the store without that? Also: does it change in the Redux Devtools?